# Find the equation of the line joining the points of contact of the tangents to a curve

Tags: circles, tangent-line

I study maths as a hobby. I am stuck on this question:

Find the values of c for which the line $2x-3y = c$ is a tangent to the curve $x^2+2y^2=2$ and find the equation of the line joining the points of contact.

I have established that $c=\pm \sqrt17$.

To get the line joining the points of contact I thought one way would be to start by finding the points of contact.

For $c =\sqrt 17$ the equation of the line is y = $\frac{2x-\sqrt 17}{3}$ and the equation of the curve is $y = \sqrt \frac{2-x^2}{2}$

At the tangent

$\frac{2x-\sqrt 17}{3} = \sqrt \frac{2-x^2}{2}$

$\rightarrow \frac{4x^2-4x\sqrt17+17}{9} = \frac{2-x^2}{2}$

$\rightarrow 17x^2-8x\sqrt17+16=0$

$\rightarrow x = \frac{8\sqrt17\pm\sqrt1088-1088}{34}=\frac{8\sqrt17}{34}$  but proceeding in this fashion seems very messy and I don't see how it will lead to the answer given in the book as $3x+4y=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly more calc 1 approach that Jose's answer.

You know that the tangent line you're looking for has slope $\frac{2}{3}$, so we can take the derivative of your curve with respect to $x$ and plug in that information.

The derivative of your curve, using implicit differentiation, is

$$
2x+4yy'=0 \implies y' = -\frac{x}{2y}.
$$

Plugging in the desired slope gives that $y=\frac{-3}{4}x$. Since we have this relation between the points, we plug back into the equation for the curve itself and find that

$$
x^2 + 2\cdot\frac{9}{16}x^2 = 2 \implies x= \pm \frac{4}{\sqrt{17}}, y= \mp\frac{3}{\sqrt{17}}.
$$

With these two solutions, plug into the equation of the line to find the possible values for $c$:

$$
c=2\cdot\pm \frac{4}{\sqrt{17}} - 3\cdot \mp \frac{3}{\sqrt{17}} = \pm \sqrt{17}.
$$

To address your final question, we know that any two points on the plane determine a line and we can write down that line using point slope form:

$$
(y-\frac{3}{\sqrt{17}}) = -\frac{3}{4}(x + \frac{4}{\sqrt{17}}) \implies y= -\frac{3}{4}x,
$$ the line you desired.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x,y)=x^2+2y^2$. Then $\nabla f(x,y)=(2x,4y)$. For which points $(x,y)$ from that curve is it true that $\nabla f(x,y)$ is orthogonal to the line $2x-3y=c$? That occurs if and only if$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\frac{4y}{2x}=-\frac32\\x^2+2y^2=2.\end{array}\right.$$This system has two solutions: $\pm\left(-\frac4{\sqrt{17}},\frac3{\sqrt{17}}\right)$. Besides,$$2\times\left(-\frac4{\sqrt{17}}\right)-3\times\frac3{\sqrt{17}}=-\sqrt{17}\quad\text{and}\quad2\times\left(\frac4{\sqrt{17}}\right)-3\times\left(-\frac3{\sqrt{17}}\right)=\sqrt{17},$$and therefore the possible values of $c$ are $\pm\sqrt{17}(\approx\pm4.12)$.

The line joining the points of contact is the line joining $\left(-\frac4{\sqrt{17}},\frac3{\sqrt{17}}\right)$ and $\left(\frac4{\sqrt{17}},-\frac3{\sqrt{17}}\right)$, which is $3x+4y=0$.

Comment: My maths is not yet advanced enough to follow all your workings out. For example, I am unfamiliar with the $\nabla$ notation. But I shall study your answer to improve my understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of ellipse is $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{y^2}{1} = 1 \implies a = \sqrt2, b = 1$ where $a$ is semi-major axis and $b$ is semi-minor axis.

If you have already found value of $c = \pm \sqrt{17}$, you know the equations of tangent lines are,

$ \displaystyle 2x - 3y = \pm \sqrt{17} \implies \pm\frac{2x}{\sqrt{17}} \mp \frac{3y}{\sqrt{17}} = 1$ ...$(i)$

We know that tangent to a point $(x_1, y_1)$ on ellipse $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ is given by $\displaystyle \frac{x x_1}{a^2} + \frac{y y_1}{b^2} = 1$

Comparing with $(i)$, $\displaystyle x_1 = \pm \frac{2a^2}{\sqrt{17}}, y = \mp \frac{3b^2}{\sqrt{17}}$. So points are $ \displaystyle \left(\pm \frac{4}{\sqrt{17}}, \mp \frac{3}{\sqrt{17}} \right)$.

The line between the two points is indeed $3x + 4y = 0$

Comment: and I do not know how you obtained $c$ but an easy way will be to use the same formula to find $c$ by plugging $x = \frac{4}{c}, y = - \frac{3}{c}$ into the equation of ellipse.

Comment: Unfortunately, the maths of ellipses is some way further on in my textbook so I am not yet able to follow all the reasoning. It will be some months before I am at that stage. But I shall study your answer to gain what I can. Thank you.

Comment: ok. my point is that as long as you know that tangent line to ellipse at point $(x_1, y_1)$ is given by $\frac{x x_1}{a^2} + \frac{y y_1}{b^2} = 1$, it is just simple comparison of equations to find points of contacts. There is no derivatives etc. required at all.